# Swift 2.1 tableView is not showing data - invalid capability, invalid name (15)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift2

I am working on an iOS app using Swift. And I need to show a tableView after a button is pressed. In somehow I ended up using a subview to show my table after the button is pressed. So in the action I just wrote `self.subview.hidden = false` and the view has appeared containing the table, but the problem is the tableView is not showing any data ! After debugging I discovered that it doesn't enter the tableView functions which returns the `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and I get this message in the console:

```
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability 
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)
```

Note that I have connected the tableView with datasource and delegate, 
Is there something wrong with the idea of showing a table in an action?

Here is the function :

```
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar){
    retrievedResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    DirectorySearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    var searchString = DirectorySearchBar.text
    if (searchString != ""){
    self.subView.hidden = false
    retrievedResults = searchForObjects(searchString!)
    for res in retrievedResults{
        print(res.USER_NAME)
        self.SearchResultsTableView.reloadData()
    }
    }
}
```

And Here are the functions that aren't working

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(tableView == self.DirectoryList){

    if Selector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        return Students.count
    } else {
        return Graduates.count
        }
    } else
    {
        return retrievedResults.count
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(tableView == self.DirectoryList){
    let cell = self.DirectoryList.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DirectoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        if Selector.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = Students[indexPath.row].0
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = Graduates[indexPath.row].0
        }
        return cell
    }

    else {
        let cell = self.SearchResultsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("searchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        print(retrievedResults[indexPath.row].FULL_NAME)
        cell.textLabel?.text = retrievedResults[indexPath.row].FULL_NAME
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: @lukeslvi The code is added now

Comment: Add your `numbeOfRowsInSection` + `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as well as the arrays with the data @Nada

Comment: @lukeslvi added , Note that the first case DirectoryList is working where the view is loading and it shows the data.. The issue is when I show the other table view SearchResultsTableView

Comment: Could you show code where you assign the datasource and delegate of the `SearchResultsTableView `?

Comment: What does your class definition look like? I'm not familiar with UISearchBar, but I'm assuming you need to add the `UISearchBarDelegate` in the class definition or drag it in the MainStoryBoard. PS, What does `DirectoryList`  contain? Maybe there are no objects so it doesn't return anything. RetrievedResults as well? How are you getting this data? The more you can explain the more someone can help.

Comment: @YuchenZhong I have connected the table with the main View delegate and datasource via the StoryaBoard

Comment: @lukesIvi It does contain data , both tables are .. the problem is the one that I just showed in the function is not showing the data in the cells but the array itself has values .. and I did the UISearchBarDelegate declaration and the search function is working fine :(

Comment: Maybe it is you don't have numberOfSections function?

Comment: I would suggest simplifying the numberOfRowsInSections else if statements. There are way too many. Make it into 1 if else statement. Maybe that's thats the issue? Have you tried printing to the logs and seeing what comes out of those array values?